# Manage multiple Threads in a Server with 2 Clients , in C

Tags: c, multithreading, server, client

I have to create a server that allows connections from 2 different clients. So I used threads. Clients and Server communicate well but I have a problem with threads. Basically with the first Client (User that select the type of coffee) I want to send the price of the coffee to the Server. Then I want to send this price from Server to another client (Then i have to insert coins and other things that I have to implement).

When I run the server and the first client the server returns me the price so it is ok. But, when I try to connect the other Client the program returns errors. Ignore the first part and look where there are threads. I know there is an error here, but I can't find it.

When i run the the first client:

```
iMac:bin $ ./client1 localhost
```

On the server I have this:

```
Price received from client1: 0.500000 €
```

Instead when I run the second client:

```
iMac:bin $ ./client2 localhost
Price received from server = 0
```

On the server I have this:

```
read() failed: Undefined error: 0
```

The price received from the server should be = 0.500000€ but I made errors. The Server enter again in prodSelected() but I want that when I run client2 the server enter only in insertCoin(). And I want that the server, when client1 is called, enter only in prodSelected(). So in CLIENT1 I want to select the coffee, CLIENT1 send the price of the coffe to the SERVER, and the SERVER send the price of the coffee to CLIENT2.

Thank you so much for your time. And forgive me for my english.

This is the server:

```
#include"funzioni.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    
#include<stdlib.h>    
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>   
#include<pthread.h> 


void *prodSelected(void *);
void *insertCoin(void *);
float price= 0; //GLOBAL VARIABLE WHERE PRICE IS STORED

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

  //Create socket
  socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
  if (socket_desc == -1)
  {
    printf("Il socket non può essere creato");
  }
  puts("Socket creato");

  //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  server.sin_port = htons( 3490 );


  //Bind
  if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
  {
    //print the error message
    perror("bind() fallito. Errore");
    return 1;
  }
  puts("bind() avvenuto con successo");

 //Listen
 listen(socket_desc , 3);

  //Accept and incoming connection
 puts("Attendendo connessioni in entrata...");
 c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);


  //Accept and incoming connection
  puts("Attendendo connessioni in entrata...");
  c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);



  pthread_t product;
  pthread_t coin;

  while( (client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
 {
    puts("Connection accettata");

    if( pthread_create( &product, NULL , &prodSelected, (void*) &client_sock) != 0){
        perror("Il thread non può essere creato");
        return 1;
    }





    if( pthread_create( &coin , NULL , &insertCoin, (void*) &client_sock) != 0){
        perror("Il thread non può essere creato");
        return 1;
    }



   if(pthread_join( coin , NULL)!=0){
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join() Errore");
            exit(0);
    }
    if(pthread_join( product , NULL)!=0){
         fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join() Errore");
         exit(0);
    }


    puts("Handler assegnato");
  }

  if (client_sock < 0){
     perror("accept() fallito");
     return 1;
  }

 return 0;
}


pthread_mutex_t client1=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


/*
 * Handle client connection
 * */

//Receive price of the product from Client1
void *prodSelected(void *socket_desc){

 int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
 int received_int = 0;
 int return_status;
 pthread_mutex_lock(&client1);
 return_status = read(sock, &received_int, sizeof(received_int)); //
 if (return_status > 0) {
   fprintf(stdout, "Product selected = %d\n", ntohl(received_int));
 }
else {
    perror("read() failed ");
    exit(1);
 }

 //these are some function included in my header file

 stampaPrezzo(ntohl(received_int)); 
 prezzo = comunicaPrezzo(ntohl(received_int));
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&client1);
 printf("Price received from client1: %f €\n",price );
 return 0;
}

 // Send price from Server to Client2.
 void *insertCoin(void *arg){

 int sock = *(int*)arg;
 int number_to_send = price;
 int converted_number = htonl(number_to_send);
 write(sock, &converted_number, sizeof(converted_number));


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should read document about accept() in detail.

```
DESCRIPTION
       The  accept()  system  call  is used with connection-based socket types
       (SOCK_STREAM,  SOCK_SEQPACKET).   It  extracts  the  first   connection
       request  on  the queue of pending connections for the listening socket,
       sockfd, creates a new connected socket, and returns a new file descrip‐
       tor  referring  to that socket.  The newly created socket is not in the
       listening state.  The original socket  sockfd  is  unaffected  by  this
       call.
```

**accept() returns a new fd referring to a client-server connection.**

The repository can solve your problem: https://github.com/yorickdewid/Chat-Server

Comment: Ok now I understand my errors, thanks. But I have 3 files: server.c, client1.c and client2.c. When I run the server I want that client1 enter only in prodSelect() and client2 only in insertCoin(), and I can't understand what I have to do. I want that the 2 client enter in their function automatically. I don't want to type for example "INSERT COIN" and then the server allows me to enter in insertCoin(). When i run ./client1 localhost I want to select the product and when i run ./client2 localhost I want to insert coin. In the repository  you have to type on the terminal what you want to do.

Comment: For server, there is no difference between clients. All of them are just socket connections, so they have to tell server who they are. In your case, client1 must tell server that it is client1 by a message. Client2 is the same. Then server can decide how to deal with them, prodSelect() or insertCoin().  In short, it is impossible for server to automatically recognize clients without any extra messages.

Comment: Damn, It's true.. So I have to run a client and type for example "Select Product", and then the server will do prodSelect(), for client2 is the same, so I type "Insert coin" in the terminal and the server will do insertCoin(). Only in this way the server will recognize the client. So I delete client2.c that is unnecessary because I need only a program for the client and another for the server. In short, when I run the client the server will display a list of functions that it can do and then with the client I have to select the function that I want to be executed. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, just like email client. Although many users are using email service with different accounts, only one email client is enough. It is unnecessary and impossible to write clients for each user. You'd better take time to design your overall framework before writing code, it is very helpful. Good luck!